# Existence of orthogonal vectors

Tags: vectors

In any given vector space, does an orthogonal vector to any given vector actually have to exist? So, if you have a vector a, does there have to exist a vector b so that b is orthogonal to a?
I'm sorry if it's a dumb question, but I couldn't actually find the answer anywhere.

Comment: Do you mean *general* vector space? Then orthogonality is not even defined. For the familiar spaces $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{C}^n$, with the usual inner product, the answer is yes. There is the trivial choice $b$ equal to the zero vector, and for $n\ge 2$ there are non-trivial choices for $b$.

Comment: @Sarah what about $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @André Nicolas: Okay, so as long as an inner product is defined and the dimension is bigger than or equals two, there will exist a non-zero orthogonal vector to any given one, or did I get something wrong?

Comment: @zed111: I'm sorry, but could you please clarify what you mean?

Comment: @Sarah I was saying orthogonality is not even defined for the vector space $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @Sarah: Apologies, I was away.  The $0$ vector is orthogonal to any vector, so we don't even need the condition dimension $\gt 1$. But for the existence of a non-trivial $b$, we do need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take two linearly independent vectors $a$ and $b$ and form the combination $\lambda a+b$. Then solve $a\cdot(\lambda a+b)=\lambda a^2+a\cdot b=0$, i.e $\lambda=-\dfrac{a\cdot b}{a^2}$.

$a$ and $b-\dfrac{a\cdot b}{a^2}a$ are orthogonal.

Comment: So it doesn't work in a vector space of dimension $1$.